# Firebase Database from a library - mixed with app's Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-library, aar

I'm building a library that is using Firebase database.
when i'm taking the exported .aar and importing it via another app - i get the following error:

**FirebaseAuthException: This operation is not allowed**

the original app didnt allow the firebase database option - so we get this message. problem is I don't need to use the app's Firebase database within the sdk - what I want is the lib's (aar) firebase database to modify.

maybe if there was a way to define two google-services.json files, one for the aar and one for the app - without them overriding themselves?

how can an autonomous firebase database within a library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to have an instance of FirebaseApp created from your library credentials. See [this blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app.html), it might help.

Instead of creating and managing 2 different google.json files (I'm not sure whether it's possible or not but even if it is..), i think it's better to wrap your library's firebase database instance and expose a neat api for the consumer apps to interact with your library's database.

Comment: Sure (y) .. In the past, I've followed this and successfully implemented multiple databases in a single app.